# Finding the form of $T_{\mu\nu}$ from different constraints of the theory

Tags: conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to understand how we derive the stress-energy in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.05057) paper in section 4.1 where the author finds
$$
T_{zz}=-\frac{3}{z_0^4}F\left(\frac{z_1}{z_0}\right)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;T_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{1}{z_0^4}F\left(\frac{z_0}{z_1}\right)
$$
The metric is given by $$ds^2 = a^2(z)(dz^2+dx^\mu dx_\mu)$$
where the function $a(z)$ has simple poles at $z=\pm \frac{z_0}{2}$ and a minimum at $z=0$.

From this I understand how we can use the Einstein's equations to derive
$$
3\left(\frac{a'}{a}\right)^2-\frac{3a^2}{L^2_{\text{AdS}}}=8\pi G T_{zz}
$$
which is the $zz$ component of the Einstein's equations.

Here we have two CFT's which we denote by $\text{CFT}_0$ and $\text{CFT}_1$ which are defined on the interval $z\in[-\frac{z_0}{2},\frac{z_0}{2}]$ and $z\in[-\frac{z_1}{2},\frac{z_1}{2}]$. The two CFTs are connected by the interface they share(which one can see in figure 12 of the reference).

The expressions for $T_{zz}$ and $T_{\mu\nu}$ are given using the $2+1$ Poincaré symmetry and conformal invariance as well as the conservation($\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=0$?) and tracelessness($g_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}=0$?) of the tensor. Finally dimensional analysis was used to determine the dependence due to $z_0,z_1$. I don't understand how we derive this form of $T_{zz},T_{\mu\nu}$ using these properties. Furthermore, what is the function $F$?

Comment: In regular CFT (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05000), do you understand how to use kinematics to show that 1pt functions are zero, while 2pt and 3pt functions are known up to a constant? Next, in boudnary CFT (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4258) do you understand how to use kinematics to show that 1pt functions are known up to a constant? Asking what is $F(z_1 / z_0)$ is like asking what is $G(u, v)$ for a flat-space 4pt function. The answer depends on the CFT.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In a later section of the paper it seems like F is a function that determines the degrees of freedom of the CFT but I don't understand how that works. As for the correlation functions, I understand the derivations coming from CFT. My problem is when we apply the conditions to the stress energy tensor.

Comment: What he's writing is a correlation function just without the brackets. It's a one-point function which is non-vanishing because there's an interface.